# No UIControls responding to user events

Tags: objective-c, events, user-interface, ios, first-responder

I am creating an iOS app without using Interface Builder and I seem to be missing something vital whereby the controls I am creating (`UITextField`, `UIButton`, etc.) are not responding to touch events.

Here's my view hierarchy:

```
UIWindow->UIView->(UITextField, UIButton)
```

I am able to create the above hierarchy and everything is showing up fine on the screen, but tapping on the `UITextField` or the `UIButton` do nothing. I also tried adding some `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass instances to the `UIView` to no avail.

I am able to call `becomeFirstResponder` on the `UITextField` and the application starts with the keyboard up and able to receive input. However when the keyboard is dismissed the interface goes back to its "dead" mode.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was calling `init` on my `UIWindow` instead of `initWithFrame:`. For some reason everything was drawing correctly but the `UIWindow` was not responding to events because every user tap was outside the bounds of the zero-size window.